# Perl/Swig/Python/Postgresql/C++ Script just stops executing, only getting "Premature end of script headers"

Tags: perl, version, swig

This is hard to explain in a few sentences. I have spent the last 5 days trying to figure this out, so now I'm asking here as a last resort. I am trying to run a pool physics library with tournament server, built by the Stanford University Computational Billiards Group, available at http://www.stanford.edu/group/billiards/

It provides a tournament server using apache2, postgresql and perl. I have been able to enable functions like logging in or creating simple matches, but the communication with AI clients does not work. The client is a C++ application I'm running in a terminal, its fetching commands from the server and its printing this error:

```
XMLRPC error: Unable to transport XML to server and get XML response back.  HTTP response code is 500, not 200
```

And the apache2 error.log is printing this:

```
[Thu May 17 21:30:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: api.pl
```

I tried running it with CGI::Debug but didnt get any more output. I have been able to identify the line it fails at with some debug outputs (one after every line :) ) and it's in this function, on the line between the print STDERRs:

```
package Pool::Rules::GameState;

sub addToDb {
  my $self=shift;
  my $timeleft=shift || $self->timeLeft();
  my $timeleft_opp=shift || $self->timeLeftOpp();
#print STDERR "uh uh uh".$self." ".$self->timeLeft()." ".$self->timeLeftOpp()." ".$timeleft." ".$timeleft_opp."\n";
  my $playingSolids = ($self->isOpenTable() ? undef : ($self->playingSolids()?1:0));
 # print STDERR "addToDb: X".$self->isOpenTable()."X Y".$self->playingSolids()."Y Z".$playingSolids."Z\n";
  $Pool::dB::dbh->do('INSERT INTO states (turntype,cur_player_started,playing_solids,timeleft,timeleft_opp,gametype) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',{},
                     $self->getTurnType(),$self->curPlayerStarted()?1:0,$playingSolids,$timeleft,$timeleft_opp,$self->gameType()) or STDERR $DBI::errstr;
  my $stateid=$Pool::dB::dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT lastval()');
  $self->tableState()->addToDb($stateid);
  return $stateid;
}
```

It's only simple getter-methods. And still, it just stops executing. The code of the getter-methods has been generated by swig. The first print-line prints this:

```
uh uh uhPool::Rules::GameState=HASH(0x99fa99c) 0 0 00:10:00 00:10:00
```

Which seems to be okay, just curious that the $self->-getters only print 0. Since the library is from Stanford University and actual competitions have been held with it, I find it hard to believe that this is an error in the code. It just seems to be a bit too old to work  (I had to make some adjustments on other places to make it work on more recent versions of libraries, f.ex. I added a < cstddef >-include in another file unrelated to this perl-issue). I first tried making it run on current versions, which I failed. Then I tried to install it on the versions the readme.txt sais it's been tested for (Ubuntu 8.10, Perl 5.10 and so on), but at some point my Ubuntu 8.10 installation always died and I had to reinstall (I tried this ~4 times, the gnome-terminal always Segmentation faulted). So now I'm back in Ubuntu 12 trying to make it work. I dont know much about perl, only the little I have been able to pick up over the last few days trying to get this to run.

Does anyone have an idea what could be triggering this kind of behavior? Is anyone aware of any compatibility issues that may be related to this? If you need any additional information just ask and I'll provide it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apache generally redirects STDERR output to an `error_log` file.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes I did, the output is:   
    [Thu May 17 22:33:47 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: api.pl

Comment: Google "perl CGI premature end of script headers" and you will get some ideas ([for example](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=262011)). This is a very common problem. Basically, your script generated output (probably an error message) before the HTTP headers were output.

Comment: Your task is to find out what that error message was, and fix it. The page i linked to in my previous comment has a few good strategies to accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I stumpled upon that page a few days ago and worked through every point. I was not able to get any more error outputs than the "premature end of script headers".